# Filtering security Qs dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

First off: The title should read filtering security questions dropdown lists but apparently, I can't use the word questions or question in the title.

I am looking [at this code example](http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/filtering-select-boxes/) but it doesn't seem valid anymore. Anyone know why and how to fix it?

I want to filter security questions such that if I select questiona from the list of questions, for the next questions, I no longer see questiona in the list of security questions. This is to prevent duplicate selection of security questions.

Here's a copy of the sample from the link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>CSS Newbie Example: Filtering Select Boxes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="select.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
   $('.security').change(function () {
      $('.security option').show(0);
      $('.security option:selected').each(function () {
         oIndex = $(this).index();
         if (oIndex > 0) {
            $('.security').each(function () {
               $(this).children('option').eq(oIndex).not(':selected').hide(0);
            });
         }
      });
   });
   $('.security').change();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
   <h1>Intelligent Filtering of Select Boxes</h1>
   <p>The following three select boxes contain the same options. But once you've selected one of the options from one select box, that item is removed from the subsequent boxes, preventing duplicate selections. <a href="http://www.cssnewbie.com/intelligent-select-box-filtering/">Return to the original article.</a></p>
   <h2>Select Your Security Questions:</h2>
   <p>
   <select class="security" name="security1">
      <option value="0">Select a question from the following options.</option>
      <option value="1">Who's your daddy?</option>
      <option value="2">What is your favorite color?</option>
      <option value="3">What is your mother's favorite aunt's favorite color?</option>
      <option value="4">Where does the rain in Spain mainly fall?</option>
      <option value="5">If Mary had three apples, would you steal them?</option>
      <option value="6">What brand of food did your first pet eat?</option>
   </select>
   </p>
   <p>
   <select class="security" name="security2">
      <option value="0">Select a question from the following options.</option>
      <option value="1">Who's your daddy?</option>
      <option value="2">What is your favorite color?</option>
      <option value="3">What is your mother's favorite aunt's favorite color?</option>
      <option value="4">Where does the rain in Spain mainly fall?</option>
      <option value="5">If Mary had three apples, would you steal them?</option>
      <option value="6">What brand of food did your first pet eat?</option>
   </select>
   </p>
   <p>
   <select class="security" name="security3">
      <option value="0">Select a question from the following options.</option>
      <option value="1">Who's your daddy?</option>
      <option value="2">What is your favorite color?</option>
      <option value="3">What is your mother's favorite aunt's favorite color?</option>
      <option value="4">Where does the rain in Spain mainly fall?</option>
      <option value="5">If Mary had three apples, would you steal them?</option>
      <option value="6">What brand of food did your first pet eat?</option>
   </select>
   </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is up with that page. View the source to see that a `<script>` tag is being escaped and rendered as `&lt;script&gt;`. This is fine for showing the source code aside from the example- but there is no actual copy of that code on the page. Consequently, no JS is not going to run as you may expect in this "live" example. Other than that, this works fine. Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbfbxvoo/) with the same code.

```
// -- works fine
$(function () {
   $('.security').change(function () {
      $('.security option').show(0);
      $('.security option:selected').each(function () {
         oIndex = $(this).index();
         if (oIndex > 0) {
            $('.security').each(function () {
               $(this).children('option').eq(oIndex).not(':selected').hide(0);
            });
         }
      });
   });
   $('.security').change();
});
```

Furthermore, checking out some comments...

> This does not work in an IE browser, safari, or chrome.

> Hm… doesn’t work in Google Chrome on Mac OS X…

Leads be to believe something is just astray with the site. Interestingly, running it in FF does work. Chrome and IE are broke.

Comment: @KalaJ cool and best of luck moving forth. I added some additional findings to answer. Weird- something is up with site. Regardless, the code is quite clean and this will surely work for you

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. And it's simplier

```
$(function () {
   // a bit of caching:
   var sec = $('.security');
   sec.change(function () {
       sec.find('option').show().end().each(function(){
           $('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]:not(:selected):not([value="0"])', sec).hide();
       });
   }).change();
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mp05gaha/)

---

**EDIT**

I don't investigated code in the link example, but instead I have created code based on requirements.
As [*@sal niro*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30673991/962734) figured out, there's a problem with the site, so his answer is fully acceptable for the question.
I'll leave my code as an alternative.